# Listing the files and taking the paths (location) of them

Tags: android, client, sftp

I create an Android ftp client, I created a stfp server in Ubuntu, I connected server, but I need a code to list the files and select one file from a list and finally learn the path of selected file. Here is the connection code :

```
 try {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = null;
    session = jsch.getSession("***", "***.***.***.***",22);
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setPassword("****");
    session.connect();                  
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect();
    ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
    sftpChannel.exit(); 
    session.disconnect();                   
} catch (JSchException e) {
    writeToSDFile(" "+e.toString());    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Please post your attempts and where you are stuck.

Comment: no becaus i didn't have any idea @The Unfun Cat

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ls` command to list the files from a specified folder. You can find the JSCH API javadoc [here](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/javadoc/)

```
  sftpChannel .ls(filesPath);
```

I didn't understand exactly what u mean by "learn path of selected file"? When you have path only you can list all files of the folder.

Comment: i try this code but it doesn't work,i can learn filename,longname but i can't take path.i want to take the files'path n server.for example:(\home\user1\desktop\abc.txt) that is path of abc.txt.i want to learn this path with code  @Srinivas